# How to Remove Bulk Dynamic Date Format in PHP?

Tags: php, str-replace

i have sentences this, and i want every sentence which found by date format will be removed

```
$mysent = 'Jul 2, 2014 . I went to special place. Aug 30, 2015 . We went to Paris.';
```

I try use this array :

```
$sasi   = array('Jan ','Feb ','Mar ','Apr ','May ','Jun ','Jul ','Aug ','Sep ','Oct ','Nov ','Dec ');
$angka  = range(1,2015); 
$bulan  = $sasi.$angka.", ".$angka;

$contoh = str_replace($bulan,'',$contoh);

echo $contoh;
```

but the date format didn't removed, help me, thank

Comment: do you really intend to concatenate the range array in your string? doesn't make sense

Comment: should i used $angka in array too sir,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions:

```
$string = 'Jul 2, 2014 . I went to special place. Aug 30, 2015 . We went to Paris.';
$result = preg_replace('/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d+,\s\d{4}\s\.\s/i', '', $string);
echo $result;
```

Outputs:

```
I went to special place. We went to Paris.
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/h82y-ucku